What does \$$1 mean in this shell function?
I saw this function definition from "Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook", I wonder why there needs two $ sign is needed in the last part of eval $1=\"$2\$\{$1:+':'\$$1\}\". How to understand each of the $ sign in entire eval condition? Thanks!
prepend() { [ -d "$2" ] && eval $1=\"$2\$\{$1:+':'\$$1\}\" && export $1 ; }


If one of the answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If you prefer, you are welcome to post an answer of your own, and accepting that. Accepting an answer helps future visitors by marking your problem as resolved. See also help.

In addition to @tripleee's correct answer, I want to suggest you to try this at command line:
set -- foo bar
echo $1=\"$2\$\{$1:+':'\$$1\}\"

foo="bar${foo:+:$foo}"

Alternatively
As eval is evil, here is an alternative (but care evil is in details read further!):
prepend() {
    [[ -d $2 ]] &&
        printf -v "$1" '%s' "$2" "${!1+:}" "${!1}" &&
        export "$1"
}

which could be written as oneliner:
prepend() { [[ -d $2 ]]&&printf -v "$1" '%s' "$2" "${!1+:}" "${!1}"&&export "$1";}

Tests:
mkdir /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
prepend myVar /tmp/foo 
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/foo'

prepend myVar /tmp/bar 
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/bar:/tmp/foo'

prepend myVar /tmp/baz
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/bar:/tmp/foo'

Sanitizing:
Regarding @jhnc's comment, you could want to sanitize submitted variable name:
Let's try (again):
prepend 'h[`date +%c.%N>/dev/tty`]' /tmp/foo

Mon Nov 25 08:04:26 2024.549285838
Mon Nov 25 08:04:26 2024.552602686
Mon Nov 25 08:04:26 2024.554057179
bash: export: `h[`date +%c.%N>/dev/tty`]': not a valid identifier

Where date command was exectuted by prepand function (3 times)!!
To avoid this you may add a little test if stringContain ... in your command:
prepend() {
    case $1 in
        *[\`\$]* )
            return 1
        ;;
    esac
    [[ -d $2 ]] &&
        printf -v "$1" '%s' "$2" "${!1+:}" "${!1}" &&
        export "$1"
}

In one line:
prepend() { case $1 in *[\`\$]* ) return 1;;esac;[[ -d $2 ]]&&printf -v "$1" '%s' "$2" "${!1+:}" "${!1}"&&export "$1";}

Or two lines:
prepend() { case $1 in *[\`\$]* ) return 1;;esac
  [[ -d $2 ]] && printf -v "$1" '%s' "$2" "${!1+:}" "${!1}" && export "$1" ;}

Then
unset myVar
prepend myVar /tmp/foo 
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/foo'

prepend myVar /tmp/bar 
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/bar:/tmp/foo'

prepend myVar /tmp/baz
echo ${myVar@A}

declare -x myVar='/tmp/bar:/tmp/foo'

Upto there, everything look fine. Then finally:
prepend 'h[`date>/dev/tty`]' /tmp/foo

prepend 'h[$(date>/dev/tty)]' /tmp/foo

Nothing! but:
echo $?

1


since your alternative assumes $1 expands to a safe value the original eval was also safe. v='h[$(date)]'; printf -v "$v" blah blah - although the :$foo should be in double-quotes

@jhnc Thanks! I've edited my answer to cite your comment and add a sanitisation step

Because it wants to inject a literal dollar sign followed by the value of $1.
In other words, if you prepend foo bar, you get
foo="bar${foo:+':'$foo}"

The parameter expansion ${foo:+value} produces value if $foo is set and non-null, and nothing otherwise. In other words, here, it takes care to insert a colon before the old value only if the old value was non-empty (and nothing at all if the old value wasn't set; it might as well have been ${foo:+:}$foo, except that will produce an error under set -u).
